# Remove hooks for specific modes

Tags: hooks

I want to delete trailing whitespace on save for every mode except `org-mode`.

In my `.emacs`, I have the following line:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

I use the `use-package` macro, and I tried adding `(remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)` to my `:config` block, but that removes the hook globally. How can I remove it specifically for `org-mode`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't have any experience with the `use-package` macro, but in principle, you could use the third argument to `remove-hook` which tells it to remove the function only from the local hook:

```el
(remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace t)
```

Here's the docstring for reference:

> `(remove-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional LOCAL)`
>
> Remove from the value of HOOK the function FUNCTION.
>   HOOK should be a symbol, and FUNCTION may be any valid function.  If
>   FUNCTION isn't the value of HOOK, or, if FUNCTION doesn't appear in the
>   list of hooks to run in HOOK, then nothing is done.  See `add-hook`.
>
> **The optional third argument, LOCAL, if non-nil, says to modify
>   the hook's buffer-local value rather than its default value.**

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Another great reminder to `C-h f`. I'll accept as soon as the timer runs down.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak: if it makes you feel any better, it took a very long time before I realized that it took that third argument, and it was only after someone on this site pointed it out to me.

Comment: Won't this only work if the function was explicitly *added* as LOCAL in `add-hook` to begin with? (A quick test in 24.5 seems to confirm my expectation... is there new functionality in trunk to facilitate this kind of override?)